# "above all else" means the most important?

Tags: phrases

I used google translate, I found this sentence means "the most important is xxxx"

ex:

```
Oh, and above all else, have fun!
```

It is strange to me, the 'else' here means all above not mentioned, isn't it?
so all the above mentioned is not important?

Comment: _Above_ here doesn't mean _previously mentioned_, it means _more than_. The instruction to have fun is more important than any other advice that could be given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. "Above all else" is used to emphasize that a particular thing is more important than other things. 
It's a variation of more common "Above all".